# Laravel, problema com campos Float

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Olá, estou usando o Laravel e preciso fazer um select em uma tabela, também crio um campo que traz o resultado de uma função.

meu select está assim:

```
return \DB::table("view_pins_ocorrencias")
                ->select("*", "round(geo({$dados->latitude},{$dados->longitude},latitude_ocorrencia,longitude_ocorrencia),2) as distancia")
                ->havingRaw('distancia < 400')
                ->havingRaw('distancia > 0.3')
                ->get();
```

porém ele apresenta um erro:

```
 "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'round(geo(float(-46.544233),float(-23.543453),latitude_ocorrencia,longitude_ocorrencia),2)' in 'field list' (SQL: select *, `round(geo(float(-46`.`544233),float(-23`.`543453),latitude_ocorrencia,longitude_ocorrencia),2)` as `distancia` from `view_pins_ocorrencias` having distancia < 400 and distancia > 0.3)"
```

Basicamente ele acrescenta ` (Apóstrofo) no float, ficando -14`.`xxxxxxx 
e também faz isso no Round. com isso o select não funciona. copiei essa query e tirei os ` ai o banco apresenta os resultados sem problema.

Answer (score 0):

Assim deve funcionar:

```
$select = 'round(geo('.$dados->latitude.','.$dados->longitude.',la‌​titude_ocorrencia,lo‌​ngitude_ocorrencia),‌​2) as distancia';

return \DB::table("view_pins_ocorrencias")
                ->select("*", $select)
                ->havingRaw('distancia < 400')
                ->havingRaw('distancia > 0.3')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Infelizmente ele apresentou o mesmo resultado =/, mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Estranho tente dar um `DD(select)` e veja se a string está sendo montada corretamente

Comment: Sim, fazendo o DD($select) ele mostrou corretamente. só ao chamar a função mesmo que ele altera.